# How to use regexp has whitespace in brackets by using Python3

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, brackets

My code is like this:

```
import re

s = """
    <contentID>1"""
reg = re.compile("(.|\n)+<contentID>1.*")
m = reg.fullmatch(s)
print(m)
reg = re.compile("[.\n]+<contentID>1.*")
m = reg.fullmatch(s)
print(m)
```

Seems like the regex `[.\n]` does not work, but `(.|\n)` does. Why? And how to write a RegExp when using brackets in this situation?

Comment: What the input string and the expected result ?

Comment: `[.]` matches a literal dot, not any char but a newline. Never use `"(.|\n)"`, use `.` with `re.S`. What do you mean by *And how to write a RegExp when using brackets in this situation?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `[.\n]` that matches a newline or a literal dot character, use `.` with `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` enabling the `.` to match newline symbols, too:

```
reg = re.compile(".*<contentID>1.*", re.DOTALL)
m = reg.fullmatch(s)
print(m)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ruC787)

Also, see [Python `re` reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> **`[]`**
>          Used to indicate a set of characters. In a set:
>   ...
>
> Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For example, `[(+*)]` will match any of the literal characters `(`, `+`, `*`, or `)`.

If you do not use `fullmatch` but `search`, you can just use `reg = re.compile("<contentID>1")` or `if "<contentID>1" in s`.